# Rename and replace parts with different filenames

Tags: ubuntu, bash, directory, files, rename

I know there are different questions about this topic but I have found nothing that fits my question:

I want to replace a part of a name in a folder but there are different files with different names. Only a part of them should be replaced:

This files should be change from sst_... to sstk_... but in the same folder are other different files like:

```
sst_20170420_3h.nc
sst_20170421_3h.nc
sst_20170422_3h.nc
sst_20170423_3h.nc
blh_20170420_3h.nc
blh_20170420_3h.nc
.
.
.
```

the length is different for every folder...

Can someone help me?

Comment: There seem to be several file rename tools for ubuntu and also script examples for operations like this. Have you checked any of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cd yourdirectory
for i in $(ls -1); do mv $i $(echo $i | sed 's/sst/sstk/') ; done
```